# Splitting a .gz file into specified file sizes in Java using byte[] array

Tags: java, split, gzip

I have written a code to split a .gz file into user specified parts using byte[] array. But the for loop is not reading/writing the last part of the parent file which is less than the array size. Can you please help me in fixing this?

```
package com.bitsighttech.collection.packaging;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class FileSplitterBytewise
{
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileSplitterBytewise.class);
private static final long KB = 1024;
private static final long MB = KB * KB;

private FileInputStream fis;
private FileOutputStream fos;   
private DataInputStream dis;
private DataOutputStream dos;

public boolean split(File inputFile, String splitSize)  
{  

    int expectedNoOfFiles =0;       

    try  
    {  
        double parentFileSizeInB = inputFile.length();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s([MmGgKk][Bb])");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(splitSize);
        m.matches();

        String FileSizeString = m.group(1);
        String unit = m.group(2);
        double FileSizeInMB = 0;

        try {
            if (unit.toLowerCase().equals("kb"))
                FileSizeInMB = Double.parseDouble(FileSizeString) / KB;         
            else if (unit.toLowerCase().equals("mb"))
                FileSizeInMB = Double.parseDouble(FileSizeString);          
            else if (unit.toLowerCase().equals("gb"))
                FileSizeInMB = Double.parseDouble(FileSizeString) * KB;         
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            logger.error("invalid number [" + FileSizeInMB  + "] for expected file size");
        }

        double fileSize = FileSizeInMB * MB;
        int fileSizeInByte = (int) Math.ceil(fileSize);
        double noOFFiles = parentFileSizeInB/fileSizeInByte;            
        expectedNoOfFiles =  (int) Math.ceil(noOFFiles);                    
        int splinterCount = 1;
        fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
        fos = new FileOutputStream("F:\\ff\\" + "_part_" + splinterCount + "_of_" + expectedNoOfFiles);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));  

        byte[] data = new byte[(int) fileSizeInByte];

        while ( splinterCount <= expectedNoOfFiles ) {                  

            int i;          
            for(i = 0; i<data.length-1; i++)
            {
                data[i] = s.readByte();             
            }               
            dos.write(data);
            splinterCount ++; 
            }
    }       
    catch(Exception e)  
    {  
        logger.error("Unable to split the file " + inputFile.getName() + " in to " + expectedNoOfFiles);
        return false;
    }  


    logger.debug("Successfully split the file [" + inputFile.getName() + "] in to " + expectedNoOfFiles + " files");
    return true;
}    

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    String FilePath1 = "F:\\az.gz";     
    File  file= new File(FilePath1);
    FileSplitterBytewise fileSplitter = new FileSplitterBytewise();
    String splitlen = "1 MB";

    fileSplitter.split(file, splitlen);

}
  }
```

Comment: You are working on file size, meaning an Integer (in terms of mathematics, in Java this will be mapped on a `long`) but you are rounding up some values. Why do you work on file size in Mb instead of bytes? Your calculations are likely to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to make more methods. You've got a complicated string-handling section of code in `split()`; it would be best to make a method that takes the human-friendly string as input and returns the number you're looking for. (It would also make it far easier for you to test this section of the routine; there's no way you can test it now.)

Once it is split off and you're writing test cases, you'll probably find that the error message you generate if the string doesn't contain `kb`, `mb`, or `gb` is extremely confusing -- it blames the number `0` for the mistake rather than pointing out the string does not have the expected units.

Using an `int` to store the file size means your program will never handle files [larger than two gigabytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). You should stick with `long` or `double`. (`double` feels wrong for something that is actually confined to integer values but I can't quickly think why it would *fail*.)

```
byte[] data = new byte[(int) fileSizeInByte];
```

Allocating several gigabytes like this is going to destroy your performance -- that's a potentially *huge* memory allocation (and one that might be considered under control of an adversary; depending upon your security model, this might or might not be a big deal). Don't try to work with the entire file in one piece.

You appear to be reading and writing the files one byte at a time. That's a guarantee to very slow performance. Doing some performance testing for another question earlier today, I found that my machine could read (from a hot cache) 2000 times faster using 131kb blocks than two-byte blocks. One-byte blocks would be even worse. A cold cache would be significantly worse for such small sizes.

```
        fos = new FileOutputStream("F:\\ff\\" + "_part_" + splinterCount + "_of_" + expectedNoOfFiles);
```

You only appear to ever open one file output stream. Your post probably should have said "only the first works", because it looks like you've not yet tried it on a file that creates three or more pieces.

```
catch(Exception e)
```

At this point, you've got the ability to discover *errors* in your program; you choose to ignore them completely. Sure, you log an error message, but you cannot actually debug your program with the data you log. You should log at a minimum the exception type, message, and maybe even full stack-trace. This combination of data is immensely useful when trying to solve problems, especially in a few months when you've forgotten the details of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please help me in fixing this?

I would use;

- drop the DataInput/OutputStreams, you don't need them.
- use in.read(data) to read the whole block instead on one byte at a time. Reading one byte at a time is so much slower!
- or read the whole of the data array, you are reading one less.
- stop when you reach the end of the file, it might not be a whole multiple of the size.
- only write as much as you have read, if your blocks at 1 MB byte there is 100 KB left you should only read/write 100 KB at the end.
- close your files when have finished, esp as you have a buffered stream.
- you "split" writes everything to the same file (so its not actually splitting) You need to create, write to and close output files in a loop.
- don't use fields when you could be/should be using local variables.
- would use the length as a long in bytes.
- the pattern ignores incorrect input and your pattern doesn't match the test you check for. e.g. your patten allows `1 G` or `1 k` but these will be treated as 1 MB.